# ¿Como recorrer un arreglo dentro de otro para que quede solo uno? ( Angular, typescript, javascript)

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente problema. Estoy recibiendo una respuesta de un servicio, la cual a su vez recorro con un bucle for para que me devuelva solo ciertos resultados.

El problema es que lo que obtengo son varios objetos con la informacion en cada uno de los array, como se ve en la imagen.. en el primero tengo 5, en el segundo tengo 7 resultados y asi.

Lo que necesitaria es que todo este dentro de un solo objeto y no dentro de "x" cantidad como se ve en la imagen

Como podria hacer?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De esta manera estoy recorriendo el objeto que recibo como respuesta desde el servicio y filtrando por lo que quiero que se muestre.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pasa que `filter` te devuelve un array, entonces tu estas generando un array nuevo por cada filtro

Tu lo que deceas es preguntar si

> `name.entityTypeDesc` es igual a **alguno** de los datos de `permitidos`

Para eso NO necesitas un `for`, solo debes hacer:

```
this.datosFiltrados = this.solicitudesAll.filter(name => permitidos.some(a=> a === name.entityTypeDesc));
```

Comment: Hola buenas! me gusto la propuesta, no sabia que podia hacerlo de ese modo. Intente con el codigo que me pasaste pero no me esta resultado ya que me da el siguiente error:                                                                                                    
 ERROR TypeError: string "Moneda Extranjera" is not a function
    at Array.some (<anonymous>)
    at solicitud-list.component.ts:435:85
    at Array.filter (<anonymous>)

Comment: Tambien tuve este error "No se puede asignar un argumento de tipo "String" al parámetro de tipo "(value: string, index: number, array: string[]) => unknown". El cual resolvi definiendo (name:any)

Comment: @Ema_Lop He editado la respuesta, al parecer ciertamente había un error. Favor prueba nuevamente

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta y la corrección! Me sirvió, esto resuelve el problema que tenia. Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar la función [Array.prototype.flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat).

```
this.datosFiltrados = this.datosFiltrados.flat()
```

De esta forma ya tienes todos los elementos en un solo array.

Comment: esto más que una respuesta es un cometario, edita añadiendo más detalles para enriquecer la información